# Multiclass classification with multilevel datal

Tags: machine-learning, multilevel-analysis, multi-class

I have a multi-class classification problem where some of the feature variables are nested.  The target variable is also related with time.  Which statistical models would be appropriate in this scenario?

Note: The number of levels of the nested variables is large, so scalability of the model is also an issue.

Comment: This have longered here for a week without any answers. The reason is probably that your question lacks context and detail. Can you tell us what your variables are really measuring?  How many variables? How many observations? What questions do you want to answer? ...